# Python: when to use pty.fork() versus os.fork()

Tags: python, linux, fork, kill, pty

I'm uncertain whether to use `pty.fork()` or `os.fork()` when spawning external background processes from my app. (Such as chess engines)

I want the spawned processes to die if the parent is killed, as with spawning apps in a terminal.

What are the ups and downs between the two forks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The child process created with `os.fork()` inherits stdin/stdout/stderr from parent process, while the child created with `pty.fork()` is connected to new pseudo terminal.  You need the later when you write a program like xterm: `pty.fork()` in parent process returns a descriptor to control terminal of child process, so you can visually represent data from it and translate user actions into terminal input sequences.

**Update:**

From pty(7) man page:

> A process that expects to be connected
>   to a terminal, can open the slave end
>   of a pseudo-terminal and then  be 
>   driven  by  a program  that  has 
>   opened the master end.  Anything that
>   is written on the master end is
>   provided to the process on the slave
>   end as though it was  input  typed  on
>   a  terminal.  For example, writing the
>   interrupt character (usually
>   control-C) to  the  master  device 
>   would  cause  an interrupt  signal 
>   (SIGINT)  to be generated for the
>   foreground process group that is
>   connected to the slave.   Conversely, 
>   anything  that  is written to the
>   slave end of the pseudo-terminal can
>   be read by the process that is
>   connected to the master end.

Comment: So the purpose of the pty is to keep the child IO in a separate box, instead of mixing it up with the parents stdin/out? I suppose you could do the same with os.fork and some pibes.
Does this terminal do anything else than IO?

Comment: Sure, you can implement `pty.fork()` using `pty.openpty()` and `os.fork()` (actually you can see it in `pty.py` source). But pseudo-terminal differ from pipes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal.

Comment: In pty.py I see that even the non os.forkpty code in pty.fork uses the /dev/pty device, so there must be more to it than just a paradigm of input/output. I read the comments in the top of the file, and they say: "Bugs: No signal handling.  Doesn't set slave termios and window size". Wikipedia said nothing about pty's doing stuff like that..

Answer (score 4):

In the past I've always used the `subprocess` module for this.  It provides a good api for communicating with subprocesses.

You can use `call(*popenargs, **kwargs)` for blocking execution of them, and I believe using the `Popen` class can handle async execution.

Check out the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) for more info.

As far as using `os.fork` vs `pty.fork`, both are highly platform dependent, and neither will work (or at least is tested) with windows.  The `pty` module seems to be the more constrained of the two by reading the docs.  The main difference being the pseudo terminal aspect.   So if you aren't willing to architect your code in such a way as to be able to use the `subprocess` module, I'd probably go with `os.fork` instead of `pty.fork`.

Comment: Actually it is exactly the 'pseudo terminal aspect' I would like to know more about. I've read many of the kernel docs and mans, but I haven't found out exactly when I am supposed to use witch..

Comment: From the reading I've done it talks about being able to do input/output to the terminal of the process via code.  So this to me sounds like a separate paradigm from using stdout/stdin to communicate with the application.  More info on the pseudo terminal concept here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal

Comment: When I read wikipedia, the pseudo-terminal seams like just an alternative to pipes.
When you say 'do input/output via code', do you mean stuff like delete and inset, or just standard read/write like a pipe?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudotermials are necessary for some applications that really expect a terminal. An interactive shell is one of these examples but there are many other. The pty.fork option is not there as another os.fork but as a specific API to use a pseudoterminal.