# Git commands output in a file using python in Windows 10

Tags: python, git, powershell

I am trying

```
git status *> test.txt
```

This works in powershell well but if I do this using python -

```
os.system('git status'+' *> '+log_path+'\git_output.txt')
```

fatal: '*' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

```
os.system('git status'+' 2> '+log_path+'\git_output.txt')
```

Btw, this worked! But I want all kinds of output in the file!

**What is the best way to do this?**

Comment: Powershell might interpolate
 `*`.

Comment: Note that Git itself is somewhat unusual in that it often writes "normal" output to its standard error output (file descriptor 2 in C code, `os.stderr` in Python). As [mklelement0 notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779860/github-commands-output-in-a-file-using-python-in-windows-10#comment119805131_67779992), the issue here is that PowerShell is *not being used* by `os.system`. Consider using `subprocess.Popen` to capture both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @dan1st But is there any option to use *> forcefully specifying the exact intent for it?

Comment: You can explicitely run the command in `powershell`.

Comment: @torek So does Popen work for all git commands? 
My intent is to create an automated git syncup between two repository. In order to do so I have to parse all errors and outputs

Comment: @dan1st But it won't solve my problem statement then

Comment: @AdityaSinha: it *can*, depending on what you mean by "work" and "all". :-) More seriously: Git *can* run unattended (as it does when invoked by, say, `go get`). Git *can* run attended (as it does when invoked by a user). A Git session that is intended to interact with a user may need a *controlling terminal*, such as provided by a pty: see [when to use pty.fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922254/python-when-to-use-pty-fork-versus-os-fork).

Comment: If you intended your outer Python process to pretend to be a user, doing pretend-interactions with a Git command, you may need to do all of that. If you intend your outer Python process to be simple and clean and *not* pretend to be a user, don't do any of that, and do use `subprocess.Popen` or some wrapper for it.

Comment: Also related, with more links for much more background reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34186035/1256452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [redirection from command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/redirecting-error-command-prompt) (different from powershell)

```
os.system('git status'+' 1> '+log_path+'\git_output.txt 2>&1')
```

Answer (score 1):

This implementation captures the results and writes them to a file:

```
output_file = open('git_output.txt', 'w')
output_file.write(os.popen('git status').read())
output_file.close()
```

Although it doesn't capture errors (stderr output).

Comment: The OP's only problem is  a redirection (`>`) _syntax_ problem: `os.system()` calls `cmd.exe` as the default shell, which doesn't understand PowerShell-only `*>` redirections. With `cmd.exe`-appropriate redirection syntax, `os.system()` works just fine in this case. Your code doesn't also capture _stderr_, the inclusion of which is the OP's intent.

Comment: @AdityaSinha, no, this approach doesn't capture errors (stderr output). Joep, I'm glad you value my comment, but please consider amending your answer  directly.